# Simple measure for comparison of rainfall regularity

Tags: distributions, entropy

In meteorology we have the concept of monthly rainfall, which is just the sum of daily rainfall over that month. Now, given this extreme example:

#### Situation 1:

```
First day of month: 210mm
All remaining days: 0mm

Monthly rainfall = 210 + 0 + ... + 0 = 210mm
```

#### Situation 2:

```
All days of month: 7mm
Monthly rainfall = 7 * 30 = 210mm
```

Which statistic can I use to show that Situation #2 has a more 'regular'
rainfall distribution? I'm not sure if standard deviation or entropy will give me a good result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [a short paper*](https://amboselibaboons.nd.edu/assets/81446/132.pdf) that summarizes various methods and favors a kind of scaled Shannon Entropy Index.

Personally, I prefer Simpson's Index because it avoids having to pick a small number to log when there is no rain. Lots of fields also use something very similar to measure competition or diversity, so it is easier to explain. The drawback is the potential maximum is less than 1, and it is dependent on the number of days with rainfall.

---

*Bronikowski, A., & Webb, C. (1996). Appendix: a critical examination of rainfall variability measures used in behavioral ecology studies. *Behavioral Ecology and Sociobiology*, 39(1), 27-30.

Comment: Is the Shannon entropy / Simpson's index valid for non count data ?  I also have rainfall data from multiple months and would like to do a rainfall distrubution analysis.